# How can I Import Contact list from Gmail in mvc C# using Oauth?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to import contact list from **gmail** using **mvc C#**. but without using `jquery` have you any idea how to do it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/04/import-contacts-from-gmail.html) will help.

The article will explain how to import gmail contacts of a user by using GContacts Data API provided by Google.

Or else, you can refer the following  Question
 [How to import Google contacts in ASP.NET MVC (no third party please)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834667/how-to-import-google-contacts-in-asp-net-mvc-no-third-party-please)

Comment: I was already see this url but its was not helpful for me.. thanks for suggest me..

Comment: @Urvish Updated the Answer. Still any queries, update me.